# erlang ets select bad arg

Tags: erlang, ets

erlang version **18.3**

Got an strange error with Erlang **ets:select/1**

the following code will **do select element from table and take them**  .

if I do

```
save(10), %% insert 10 data

remove(3) %% remove 3 data per time
```

it works

if I do

```
save(6007), %% insert  more datas

remove(400) %% remove 400 data per time
```

it was bad arg in `ets:select(Cont)`  also, it was **not** the in the first or second loop, but was always there.

any suggestion?

```
 -record(item, {name, age}).
 %% start the table
 start() ->
 ets:new(example_table, [public, {keypos, 2},
 named_table,
 {read_concurrency, true},
 {write_concurrency, true}]).

 %% insert n demo data
 save(Limit) ->
 All = lists:seq(1 ,Limit),
 All_rec = [#item{name = {<<"demo">>, integer_to_binary(V)} , age = V} || V <- All],
 ets:insert(example_table, All_rec).

 %% remove all data, n data per select
 remove(Limit) ->
   M_head   = #item{name = '$1', _ = '_'},
 M_guards = [],
 M_result = ['$1'],
 M_spec   = [{M_head, M_guards, M_result}],

 case ets:select(example_table, M_spec, Limit) of
      '$end_of_table' ->
      0;
      {Keys, Cont} ->

      remove(example_table, Keys, Cont, 0, [])
      end.

      remove(Table, [],  Cont, Count, _Acc) ->

        case ets:select(Cont) of
          '$end_of_table' ->
            Count;
          {Keys, Cont_1} ->

            remove(Table, Keys,  Cont_1, Count, [])
        end;
      remove(Table,[Key | T],  Cont, Count, Acc) ->
        case ets:take(example_table, Key) of
          [] ->
       remove(Table, T,  Cont, Count, Acc);
          [Rec] ->
       io:format("Rec [~p] ~n", [Rec]),
       remove(Table, T,  Cont, Count + 1, [Rec | Acc])
        end.
```

stack trace

```
     4> example_remove:save(6007).
      true
     5> example_remove:remove(500).
    ** exception error: bad argument
   in function  ets:select/1
    called as ets:select({example_table,304,500,<<>>,
                             [{<<"demo">>,<<"2826">>},
                              {<<"demo">>,<<"3837">>},
                              {<<"demo">>,<<"5120">>},
                              {<<"demo">>,<<"878">>},
                              {<<"demo">>,<<"1195">>},
                              {<<"demo">>,<<"1256">>},
                              {<<"demo">>,<<"1449">>},
                              {<<"demo">>,<<"5621">>},
                              {<<"demo">>,<<"5768">>}],
                             9})
 in call from example_remove:remove/5 (d:/workspace/simple-cache/src/example_remove.erl, line 47)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code part? Also, show us the error log you got.

Comment: I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @Lol4t0  which version of erlang are you using?

Comment: @A.Sarid  the log is updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this happens because you simultaneously iterate over the table and modify it.

I suggest wrapping main remove cycle with guards of [`safe_fixtable`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#safe_fixtable-2)

```
remove(Limit) ->
    ets:safe_fixtable(example_table, true),
    M_head   = #item{name = '$1', _ = '_'},
    M_guards = [],
    M_result = ['$1'],
    M_spec   = [{M_head, M_guards, M_result}],

    R = case ets:select(example_table, M_spec, Limit) of
        '$end_of_table' ->
            0;
        {Keys, Cont} ->
            remove(example_table, Keys, Cont, 0, [])
    end,
    ets:safe_fixtable(example_table, false),
    R.
```

Comment: Thanks. this make sense.